# Load richtextbox from memorystream. WPF/VB>NET

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have some trouble with loading a richtextbox from a memorystream.

I have some data in a database table stored as a byte array, I convert it to a string and load it into a memorystream and then I want to load that memory stream in the richtextbox. The application breaks on

Dim tr As New TextRange(rtbTemplate.Document.ContentStart, rtbTemplate.Document.ContentEnd)

though.

Code for getting the data from the database

```
    Dim TemplateData As Byte() = TemplateDataTableInstance.Rows(0).Item("TemplateData")
    Dim strTemplateData As String
    Dim enc As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding()
    strTemplateData = enc.GetString(TemplateData)

' I put a messagebox here to check if I get the data I want and I do
```

Now, how do I sort out the rest? I have

```
    Dim strDataFormat As String = DataFormats.Rtf
    Using ms As New MemoryStream(strTemplateData)
        Dim tr As New TextRange(rtbTemplate.Document.ContentStart, rtbTemplate.Document.ContentEnd)
        tr.Load(ms, strDataFormat)
    End Using
```

and my richtextbox in xaml

```
        <RichTextBox x:Name="rtbLetter">
            <RichTextBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                </Style>
            </RichTextBox.Resources>
            <FlowDocument FontSize="12" FontFamily="Times New Roman">
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim fd0 As FlowDocument = New FlowDocument
    Dim strDataFormat As String = DataFormats.Rtf
    Dim ba() As Byte = Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strDataFormat)
    Dim ms As IO.MemoryStream = New IO.MemoryStream(ba)

    Dim tr As TextRange = New TextRange(fd0.ContentStart, fd0.ContentEnd)

    tr.Load(ms, System.Windows.DataFormats.Rtf)

    ms.Close()

rtbLetter.document = fd0
```